# Perl: Adding two numbers, one of which is more than 32 bits

Tags: perl, komodo

If I have

```
my $hex_str = "fffff00000000";

my $hex_val = hex($hex_str);

my $sum = $hex_val + 5;
```

`$sum` is what I expect - `0xfffff00000005`

If I have

```
my $hex_str = "ffffff00000000";

my $hex_val = hex($hex_str);

my $sum = $hex_val + 5;
```

Komodo shows `$sum` being `0xffffff00000008`

If I have

```
my $hex_str = "fffffff00000000";

my $hex_val = hex($hex_str);

my $sum = $hex_val + 5;
```

Komodo shows `$sum` being `0xfffffff00000000`

Can someone explain to me why I get unexpected values in the second and third case?

```
>perl -V:use64bitint
use64bitint='define';

>perl -V:ivsize
ivsize='8';

>perl -V:archname
archname='MSWin32-x64-multi-thread';
```

Comment: what is $Config{ivsize}

Comment: It is 8 . What does that mean?

Comment: That is the actual number of bytes it uses for integers; use64bitint isn't as reliable.

Comment: it does look like it is truncating at 53 bits as if it is storing it in a floating point NV; don't know why though.

Comment: @ikegami this gives archname='MSWin32-x64-multi-thread';

Comment: @ikegami I use my debugger to look at the value. But let me print it and see.

Comment: @ikegami huh.. it prints the right value. I guess this is problem with the IDE I am using (Komodo). I never considered printing it. Sorry my Perl knowledge is limited. Maybe I should reply to my own question (or maybe you can) before someone downvotes my question :)

Comment: @ysth, See http://stackoverflow.com/a/40493366/589924

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't show the code you use to print $sum; that may be where the problem is, but I can't duplicate it.  In any case, if you have warnings enabled, the call to hex() is going to give you a `Hexadecimal number > 0xffffffff non-portable` warning.

You could do:

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use Math::BigInt;

my $hex_str = "ffffff00000000";
my $hex_val = Math::BigInt->new("0x$hex_str");
my $sum = $hex_val + 5;
print $sum->as_hex, "\n";
```

Comment: Thanks! You are right, with warnings enabled I get that message.

Comment: The warning simply means that it won't work on a 32-bit build, but it should work when $Config{ivsize} is 8!

Answer (score 2):

It appears that Komodo (the IDE used) or what it uses to exchange data with `perl` is using a double-precision floating point to store the 64-bit value, resulting in a loss of precision.

This causes the watch window to show the wrong value for `$sum`, but the correct value is shown when using `printf "%X\n", $sum;` from within Perl or when using `sprintf "%X", $sum` from the Kodomo watch window.

Comment: @ikegami - Thanks for looking at these. This drove me nuts. Lesson learnt - don't realy on the values Komodo shows in watch window.

Comment: The solution is to create a watch for the expression `sprintf "%X", $sum` if you can.

Comment: Please file a bug https://github.com/Komodo/KomodoEdit/issues/new (Yes you file Komodo IDE tickets with the Komodo Edit repo).  Great work digging into the issue btw.  If you create a ticket please make sure to link this forum thread.

Comment: @cgchoffman I just did  -https://github.com/Komodo/KomodoEdit/issues/2138 . Thanks!

Comment: @ikegami sprintf in watch window is a great solution!